# How to use Highcharts stock chart with benzinga API

Tags: highcharts

I am planning on using Highcharts along with the benzinga API, specifically the Historical Bar Data API shown here: https://docs.benzinga.io/benzinga/bars-v2.html

Can someone help me out with some explanation, links, sample code, etc. to help me wrap my head around how to do this?

I basically need a chart line the one in the Highcharts Stock Demos › Single line series: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock/basic-line

My main confusion is how to fetch and render the data provided by the benzinga API.

Comment: You have used the `Highcharts` tag, but your question is mostly related to fetching and using the benzinga API, not the Highcharts library.

Comment: Stackoverflow would not allow me to put a "benzinga" tag. And its both. I'm looking for help integrating the two.

Answer (score 0):

After receiving data the only thing that remains to do is to adapt data to the structure required by Highcharts.

```
 const processedData = data[0].candles.map(dataEl => ({
   ...dataEl,
   x: new Date(dataEl.dateTime).getTime()
 }));

 Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
   series: [{
     type: 'candlestick',
     data: processedData
   }]
 });
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8bmvhzyf/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.candlestick.data